# How to have multiple Smart Contracts into a single Chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I need to split my business logic into two Smart Contracts, A and B, where A adds some data on the ledger and B read's A's data directly from the ledger, for some calculation.

I need this split because:

- A and B will have different endorsement policies
- B's calculation transaction security should rely on "read-set" mechanism for validation, which I know is enforced for data that B reads directly from the ledger but I'm not sure for data read from a cross-chaincode call (and I can't find info about it)

So...

[The guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/smartcontract/smartcontract.html?source=post_page-----1b4c3034d593----------------------) says

> Multiple smart contracts can be defined within the same chaincode. When a chaincode is deployed, all smart contracts within it are made available to applications.

But I really can't find a reference on how to bundle multiple Smart Contracts into a single Chaincode (necessary thing in order to let B read A's data).

The best for my project would be having A and B in different languages (respectively, Javascript and Java) but if they need to be written in the same language to fit in the same chaincode I could rewrite the first one.

...

Can somebody help me? I actually just need a reference to explain me how to bundle multiple Smart Contracts into a Chaincode (
or an example, couldn't find that either)

Comment: There are 2 types of endorsement policy. One is defined at the chaincode level and the other defined at the key level. You can't utilise the multiple smart contract in a single chaincode capability and have chaincode level endorsement as all smart contracts in the same chaincode will be subject to the same level endorsement policy

Comment: Right, so my only chance is to find out if the read-set validation is applied for a cross-chaincode read as for a direct ledger read. Do you know if this happens automatically? Or do I have to use the same Chaincode and then the same Enforcement policies?